# Galaxy s3 breaks responsive layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, joomla

This is the site I'm developing: http://www.syndicatetx.com/

This site displays correctly on iPhone, and 4 other android devices I tested but on my galaxy s3 it appears to remove the css class for the logo.

Problem:

1. logo doesn't appear on s3
2. "Welcome to the Syndicate Where Old Jazz Comes Alive Open May 2013" Doesn't appear. The weird thing is. The text is there! just not visible.
   (You can copy and paste the text in the mobile browser)
3. If you scroll to bottom and then scroll up real quick the logo loads for 1 second then disappears.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/zod5eo9dh7tupr3/2013-05-06%2010.08.31.png

If I use chrome or firefox on s3 everything looks perfect.
If I use dolphin (with jetpack) it's perfect.
If I use dolphin (without jetpack) same as screenshot.

I realize I need to get into mobile debugging but as of right now everything I saw for mobile debugging was for chrome and firefox which displays the page correctly so doesn't really help.

Answer (score 0):

I would just leave this as a comment but don't have high enough rep yet...

I had trouble with S3 before because of its extremely high resolution in comparison to other phones.  I see that you are using 480, 750, 800px to identify devices.  Just be aware that the high resolution of that phone 1280 x 720.